# How to enter Comment in Android app pop up using Appium

Tags: android, popup, comments, appium

I am working on an automation Android app using Appium and Java. In my app when I click on Finish button there is a pop up.  This pop up requires me to enter some text data.  Then a click on the send button finishes the task.

I am unable to enter a comment.

Can someone please help me out?

Here is the code I am using:

```
public void comment() {
        MobileElement EnterComment =
                waitForVisibleElementBy(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@resource-id ='com.staffr.app:id/customPanel']"  + "/android.widget.EditText"),30);
        if (EnterComment != null) {
            EnterComment.sendKeys("This is Automation Test");
        }
```

Here is a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiSLL.png) to help:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to tap on the field and execute the command

Edited code :

```
 public void comment() {
    MobileElement EnterComment =
            waitForVisibleElementBy(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[@resource-id ='com.staffr.app:id/customPanel']"  + "/android.widget.EditText"),30);
    if (EnterComment != null) {
        EnterComment.tap();
        EnterComment.sendKeys("This is Automation Test");
    }
```